# Should the shuffle=True argument be used during training in torch.utils.data.DataLoader() when we have time series data?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, time-series, pytorch-dataloader

I am confused regarding whether the `shuffle=True` argument should be used in the pytorch `torch.utils.data.DataLoader()` during training when the training data are time series data. I believe that `shuffle=True` should be used during training in most cases, but does this apply to time series data (where the order matters) as well?

Comment: If you're using a model with memory, like LSTM, you'd want to keep the data associated with it's time sequence. The batches can be shuffled, but the samples in the batch, not so much. If there's no memory, like CNN, then you'd likely want to shuffle the data.